# JS: How to add negative numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

supposing I have variable `ex1` equal to -20 and variable `ex2` equal to 50. I try to add it in javascript as `alert(ex1+ex2);` but it alerts `-20+50`. I'm really confused with this. THanks for the help, even though it might be a really silly question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JavaScript is a weakly typed language. So, you have to be careful with the types of data which you use. Without knowing much about your program, this can be fixed like this

```
alert(parseInt(ex1, 10) + parseInt(ex2, 10));
```

This makes sure that both `ex1` and `ex2` are integers. If you think, you would be using floating point numbers

```
alert(parseFloat(ex1) + parseFloat(ex2));
```

Comment: Don't forget the radix with `parseInt()`, though `parseFloat()` might be a better choice.

Comment: @DavidThomas I was just adding that in the edit :)

Comment: Right parseInt! Thanks! I will give you the correct answer once the 10 mins is up. Sorry that was a really dumb question btw.

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know how I can improve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this

```
alert(parseInt(ex1) + parseInt(ex2));
```

Comment: Never forget the radix parameter when you use `parseInt`